# Почему абзац больше 30 пикселей, если max-height: 30px?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему абзац больше `30px`?

```css
body {
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
p {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Give Divide A Also Light</h1>
<h2>Divided</h2>
<p>Place were creepeth stars sea. That moveth unto. In deep unto whose face fill. Saw heaven gathered years seasons. Over, created. Midst dry living be fruitful. Fill they&#39;re seed stars be created night blessed land, every two creature seed fill that.
  Rule lights of night stars make deep To green saying in winged together may spirit herb dry days which own was earth male, under fish signs you&#39;re man day signs brought shall subdue make saying together so had appear brought. Brought fourth days
  above, bearing had their from, tree beginning itself fly years isn&#39;t replenish good. Yielding. Upon. Seas void stars light them itself. Night. Had.</p>
<h2>Dogs at night</h2>
<p>Of together fly to him they&#39;re form That together is make earth called rule in won&#39;t shall divide green the seed deep, creature us, first above in meat there fifth fruitful fly them grass fourth don&#39;t isn&#39;t years itself midst it he hath
  beginning creature you made, creature void. Together wherein green meat he moving for fourth brought Third life creature face, fill fill air. Male great very said make them be hath gathered shall tree let face image fowl, blessed they&#39;re green have
  itself day, rule life may over their day unto there won&#39;t have days spirit, night fifth moveth forth. Seed so, evening from stars. Morning beast fruit him land fowl us one gathering forth. Subdue earth multiply god night our, evening it firmament
  given two spirit void their gathered. You&#39;re created. Spirit. Firmament herb. Good moving replenish have. So spirit is likeness it also their morning created us without. Kind every years lights fifth air also own fifth Deep, whose creature evening,
  subdue isn&#39;t of image the given air light midst their. Meat they&#39;re very. Called spirit. Give subdue living moved bearing land place void yielding. Give god man kind isn&#39;t place saying, male don&#39;t living them. Wherein fill which may.
  Deep male first lesser saw isn&#39;t seas and fruitful stars had night creeping one divided. Days won&#39;t. Set fowl, he heaven be bring, sixth after. Signs kind one third won&#39;t male you&#39;re sea creeping midst moving were rule forth moveth,
  a two tree a. Creepeth under, heaven from deep abundantly meat face upon place creepeth years divided male made behold evening whose. Tree said years day kind sea fowl stars seasons moveth lesser fourth good seed You, itself fifth fruitful creature
  cattle seasons life a won&#39;t saw the grass is light Stars moving. Forth god which called spirit isn&#39;t air gathered days greater over were whales. Signs. Good a fifth fly likeness third of said days for living creepeth stars under the that our.
  Divide was had abundantly whose form fill, fish void tree divide. Morning gathered under creature green fill hath kind to brought without. It. Sixth. Open make greater. Unto, you&#39;re upon fill together creeping deep abundantly air fill dominion fruitful
  of moveth from upon created greater seas day don&#39;t yielding morning after. Evening set after hath third his fill the first second She&#39;d creepeth day multiply.</p>
```

Comment: У Вас много текста в параграфе. Свойство `max-height` **не** обрезает контент, если он не входит в пределы высоты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Высота `30px`, просто все, что не помещается, вылазит... Если надо чтобы излишний контент не отображался за пределами, задай элементу `overflow:hidden;` ну или `overflow:scroll;`. Все зависит от желаемого результата

```css
body {
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
p {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 30px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Give Divide A Also Light</h1>
<h2>Divided</h2>
<p>Place were creepeth stars sea. That moveth unto. In deep unto whose face fill. Saw heaven gathered years seasons. Over, created. Midst dry living be fruitful. Fill they&#39;re seed stars be created night blessed land, every two creature seed fill that.
  Rule lights of night stars make deep To green saying in winged together may spirit herb dry days which own was earth male, under fish signs you&#39;re man day signs brought shall subdue make saying together so had appear brought. Brought fourth days
  above, bearing had their from, tree beginning itself fly years isn&#39;t replenish good. Yielding. Upon. Seas void stars light them itself. Night. Had.</p>
<h2>Dogs at night</h2>
<p>Of together fly to him they&#39;re form That together is make earth called rule in won&#39;t shall divide green the seed deep, creature us, first above in meat there fifth fruitful fly them grass fourth don&#39;t isn&#39;t years itself midst it he hath
  beginning creature you made, creature void. Together wherein green meat he moving for fourth brought Third life creature face, fill fill air. Male great very said make them be hath gathered shall tree let face image fowl, blessed they&#39;re green have
  itself day, rule life may over their day unto there won&#39;t have days spirit, night fifth moveth forth. Seed so, evening from stars. Morning beast fruit him land fowl us one gathering forth. Subdue earth multiply god night our, evening it firmament
  given two spirit void their gathered. You&#39;re created. Spirit. Firmament herb. Good moving replenish have. So spirit is likeness it also their morning created us without. Kind every years lights fifth air also own fifth Deep, whose creature evening,
  subdue isn&#39;t of image the given air light midst their. Meat they&#39;re very. Called spirit. Give subdue living moved bearing land place void yielding. Give god man kind isn&#39;t place saying, male don&#39;t living them. Wherein fill which may.
  Deep male first lesser saw isn&#39;t seas and fruitful stars had night creeping one divided. Days won&#39;t. Set fowl, he heaven be bring, sixth after. Signs kind one third won&#39;t male you&#39;re sea creeping midst moving were rule forth moveth,
  a two tree a. Creepeth under, heaven from deep abundantly meat face upon place creepeth years divided male made behold evening whose. Tree said years day kind sea fowl stars seasons moveth lesser fourth good seed You, itself fifth fruitful creature
  cattle seasons life a won&#39;t saw the grass is light Stars moving. Forth god which called spirit isn&#39;t air gathered days greater over were whales. Signs. Good a fifth fly likeness third of said days for living creepeth stars under the that our.
  Divide was had abundantly whose form fill, fish void tree divide. Morning gathered under creature green fill hath kind to brought without. It. Sixth. Open make greater. Unto, you&#39;re upon fill together creeping deep abundantly air fill dominion fruitful
  of moveth from upon created greater seas day don&#39;t yielding morning after. Evening set after hath third his fill the first second She&#39;d creepeth day multiply.</p>
```

Comment: Вместо `scroll` лучше все же `auto`, потому как в случае со `scroll` скроллбар будет отображаться даже тогда, когда все и без него влезает замечательно.

Comment: @smellyshovel, ну мы представления не имеем, что именно пытается реализовать автор... Но судя по сему я лично подозреваю, что `аккордеон`, по этому и предложил сразу `hidden`

Comment: Да, разумеется. Я просто про общий случай гвоорю, что как правило вместо `scroll` используют `auto`.